# How to find header section in Magento platform?

Tags: php, html, magento, metadata

I have a website in Magento and I am relatively new to this platform and I have basic notions of HTML and PHP. I want to make an account on Google Webmasters tools and I need to confirm that the website is mine.

I have a metadata that I need to insert it in the header of the website, but I cannot find the header section. Can someone help me with this please?

Comment: Probably you need to create it. Anyway, post some code here for users to be able to help you.

Comment: Please check the your site meta tag value is admin backend

Comment: [ask], http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @Aurel  Do you want to insert some script in the header section?

Comment: @Muk: I think the OP wants to add a `<meta />` tag.

Comment: I want to add a <meta /> tag in the header to confirm the website

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did a quick google search on where the header file in magento is located it came out with this

```
app/design/frontend/base/default/template/page/html/head.phtml
```

And i assume default is the default theme ,if you have your own custom theme just follow the path to your theme.

I hope that this is what you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you guys, for all your answer. You ask me about posting some code Nick but I don't have acces to code, just the magento interface.

Answer (score 2):

You can add this code in Magento from backend. Here are the steps:

1. Login in Admin panel
2. From Top Navigation Click on `System` >> `Configuration`
3. From Left Click on `Design` Tab
4. In right Column Click on `HTML Head` Group.
5. You can add your script code in `Miscellaneous Scripts` textarea

Comment: I don't have the Design Tab in my magento interface. It's possible that is hidden under some other tabs?

Comment: I think you are not logged in with Administrators rights. you need design tab access backend login details atleast for this.

Comment: I am looged in with user name and password in the website/admin

Comment: Yes but that username don't have full rights assigned. Ask your administrator for full access

Comment: I have the design tab when I edit a product on the website. It's the same thing?

Comment: No. It is complete different.