# Location of head in Magento

Tags: php, html, magento, backend

I am trying to modify the head of my website made in the Magento platform and I am having very much trouble in dooing this. Everywhere I search I read something about app/design/frontend/default/modern/template/page/html/head.phtml

What is this? The physical location of the code ? I only have access to the Magento platform. Is there any way to have acces to the head file? I want to add a metadata (`<meta name="google-site-verification" content="quuawwomLqURQt6N34_Pr0cBlYnWcYdiRz8tdXC3Oe8" />`) in it and I tried to overwrite the XML file and failed.

I tried something like this:

```
default>
    <reference name="head">
        <block type="cms/block" name="google verification" as="google verification">
            <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>google_plus</block_id></action>
        </block>
    </reference>
</default>
```

Comment: http://www.atwix.com/magento/how-to-change-the-header-of-magento-cms-page/

Comment: I already tried this and fail :) . It's eating my nerves.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [your previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30864333/how-to-find-header-section-in-magento-platform). If you must ask a question again, please declare the similar one and explain how the answers did not assist you - otherwise it will just create duplicate work.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to add a custom meta tag to your Magento store, you need to edit the `head.phtml` file of your current running template.

`app/design/frontend/Your-template/default/template/page/html/head.phtml`

If you not found this file in your template then you can get this file in

`app/design/frontend/base/default/template/page/html/head.phtml`

Edit `head.phtml` file and flush magento cache. Refresh the page and check the source code of page.

In case if you want to add meta title and description data for specific product page then you can check the [Link](http://www.beetleweb.com/magento-seo-tutorials/meta-information).

To check which template is running currently on your site.

- Login into admin panel.
- System > configuration > under the left menu find General tab and under this you will get Design tab . Click on Design tab.
- Current Package Name is the current template name.

[image]

OR To solve your problem (easier):

Use the field Miscellaneous Scripts from System->Configuration->Design->Head and put your scripts in there.

They will be added before the `</head>` tag and you can set different scripts per website or even store views.

Comment: Sorry, but I'm feeling like rain man here. Where do I find the head.phtm file ?

Comment: You have to follow the path of your template . app/design/frontend/default/your-template/page/html/head.phtml

Comment: To check which template is running currently on your site. Login into admin panel. System > configuration > under the left menu find General tab and under this you will get Design tab . Click on Design tab.

Current Package Name is the current template name.

Comment: Sorry for beeing this stupid :) but how do i know what template do I have? It's the theme title or something like that?

Comment: Someone else told me about this design tab but i cannot find it. It is possible to be hidden?

Comment: Yes, thank you, but in my configuration file I cannot find the Design tab

Comment: go to app/design/frontend/base/default/template/page/html/. here you can get head.phtml file

Comment: Just copy the link in my browser?

Comment: You can just ctrl+u for view source. In css path you can get current template name.

Comment: Design tab is under the General section in left hand side of the page. see screenshot

Comment: This is my website www.audiomag.ro   Where in that big code do I find the template name?

Comment: I saw the screenshot but in my tabs Design it does not exist.  I would put a screenshoot myself but I am new to the stackoverflow and it dousen't allow me

Comment: You are not logged in with admin credentials or your account is not permitted for that. I checked that default is your temaplate. Put this path in   ftp  /app/design/frontend/base/default/template/page/html/ and press enter

Comment: once check in System > design

Comment: I will try later beacuse for 4 hours it's eating my nerves and I need a break to not "kill" my computer. Thank you Deep Kakkar for your time and answers :)

Comment: Ok. Good Luck! always note that if a file is not in your template then that should be in base template folder.